# Node: res.download downloads empty zipped folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, archive

My use case is such where I have to create a directory of files and return it as a zip file for the user.

My code looks like this:

```
var output = fs.createWriteStream('target.zip');

archive.pipe(output);
archive.append('details.json', { name: 'details.json'});
archive.finalize();

//Specifiy the .zip folder & Download
filename = 'target.zip';
res.download(filename);
```

This gives me an empty folder in my browser's download location.

The `target.zip` in its server's location however, contains data.

I realize this is happening because Node is not waiting for `append()` to append files to the archive.
I tried to put the code for download in the callback function of `append.finalize()` but it doesn't work.

Where do I put the download code so that it happens after the append is successful?

Comment: Check example https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/blob/master/examples/pack-zip.js

Comment: @Molda The example doesn't cover downloading to the client - where I was facing the problem.

Comment: OK but it covers how to see when the file was created using output.on('close'

Comment: So could the res.download() be put in the output.on(..'s callback function?

Comment: I haven't tried myself but I would say yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have a look at their [Example](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/blob/master/examples/express.js) on their GitHub repository.

You can set the `Attachment` property on `res` and then pipe to it.

```
//set the archive name
  res.attachment('archive-name.zip');

  //this is the streaming magic
  archive.pipe(res);
```

You must also monitor res's on 'close' to be able to end the stream when everything is done.

```
res.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Archive wrote %d bytes', archive.pointer());
    return res.status(200).send('OK').end();
  });
```

That way you can still finalize, but the download will only occur once everything is done.

Comment: Still getting an empty file?